# react-bootstrap-table: Programmatically filter by clicking from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I’m using the react-bootstrap-table component and would like to programmatically filter a column by clicking on a button from another component.

I followed the **Programmatically Select Filter** example from the [react-bootstrap-table examples list](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#column-filter) but didn’t manage to adapt it so the button from the other component can control the filter.

When I call `this.refs.nameCol.applyFilter(1);` on click, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applyFilter' of undefined

The main question is: what's the best approach to tackle this?

Test example here:

```js
var data = [
  {id : "1", name : "Item name 1", quality : "bad"},
  {id : "2", name : "Item name 2", quality : "good"},
  {id : "3", name : "Item name 3", quality : "unknown"},
  {id : "4", name : "Item name 4", quality : "good"},
  {id : "5", name : "Item name 5", quality : "good"},
  {id : "6", name : "Item name 6", quality : "bad"}
];

const qualityType = {
  'good': 'good',
  'bad': 'bad',
  'unknown': 'unknown'
};

function enumFormatter(cell, row, enumObject) {
  return enumObject[cell];
}

var FilterBtn = React.createClass({  
  handleBtnClick: function(e) {
    this.refs.nameCol.applyFilter(1); // Cannot read property 'applyFilter' of undefined
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button onClick={ this.handleBtnClick } className='btn btn-default'>Click to apply select filter</button>
    );
  }
});

var BigTable = React.createClass({  
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <BootstrapTable data={ data }>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' isKey>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn ref='nameCol' dataField='quality' filterFormatted dataFormat={ enumFormatter }
                  formatExtraData={ qualityType } filter={ { type: 'SelectFilter', options: qualityType } }>Product Quality</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
          </div>
        );
      }
  });

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <FilterBtn/>
    <BigTable/>
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#container")
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for your help!

**=======================================================================**

**UPDATE**

This has been resolved thanks to the help of @SatyaDash.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ydcgy9g/

For those interested, I also applied this approach to programmatically filter a column by this time selecting an option from a **dropdown list** from another component.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1qhfm50/5/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote your program in ES6.Find the code below.

The problem is you mentioned the select options dictionary as something and while applying filter you are passing different argument.So if you want to select good upon button click then need to pass 'good' in applyFilter function.

```
        var data = [
      {id : "1", name : "Item name 1", quality : "bad"},
      {id : "2", name : "Item name 2", quality : "good"},
      {id : "3", name : "Item name 3", quality : "unknown"},
      {id : "4", name : "Item name 4", quality : "good"},
      {id : "5", name : "Item name 5", quality : "good"},
      {id : "6", name : "Item name 6", quality : "bad"}
    ];

    const qualityType = {
      'good': 'good',
      'bad': 'bad',
      'unknown': 'unknown'
    };

    function enumFormatter(cell, row, enumObject) {
      return enumObject[cell];
    }
class FilterBtn extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleBtnClick = this.handleBtnClick.bind(this);
  }
    handleBtnClick(){
    this.props.callAF();
  }
  render(){
    return (
            <button 
                onClick={ this.handleBtnClick } 
        className='btn btn-default'>
        Click to apply select filter
            </button>
        );
  }
}
class BigTable extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        data: data
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.applyFilter !== nextProps.applyFilter){
        this.refs.nameCol.applyFilter('good');  
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable data={data}>
                    <TableHeaderColumn 
            dataField='id' 
            isKey>
            Product ID
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn 
            dataField='name'>
            Product Name
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn 
            ref='nameCol' 
            dataField='quality' 
            filterFormatted 
            dataFormat={ enumFormatter }
                        formatExtraData={ qualityType } 
            filter={{ 
                type: 'SelectFilter', 
              options: qualityType 
                        }}>
            Product Quality
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                </BootstrapTable>
            </div>
        );
  }
}
class MainClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        applyFilter : false
    }
    this.callAFF = this.callAFF.bind(this);
  }
  callAFF(){
    this.setState({
        applyFilter: true
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div>
        <FilterBtn 
            callAF={
                this.callAFF
            }/>
         <BigTable
            applyFilter={this.state.applyFilter}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <MainClass/>,
    document.querySelector("#container")
);
```

Comment: You're right, I wasn’t passing the right argument in the `applyFilter` function but this wasn’t the only change to apply to implement the solution as you added props and state inits there. Great thanks!

Comment: However I noticed the filter button worked only the first time it was clicked (if button was clicked then another option was selected from the dropdown list, clicking again on the button didn’t revert back the filter to “good”). 
I found out this was because of the `if(this.props.applyFilter !== nextProps.applyFilter)` condition. Removing this condition fixed the issue. Could you explain why this was necessary @SatyaDash?
[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ydcgy9g/)

Comment: Basically this is because componentWillReceiveProps will be called many times but we need to render again only when it is true.So you can remove that check anyway.